# ORA-00904 and the table and column definitely exist

Tags: sql, oracle

New to Oracle, here but I can't see why this isn't working and I'm going a bit nuts.

My query works fine but as soon as I add the third join statement, it gives me the below error message:

Here is my query.  Everything looks like it spelled correctly, table and column exists.  There is only one record in the TS_ORDER_SEC_SPEC directory

Error:

```
Number: 904
ErrorMessage: ORA-00904: "OSS"."ORDER_ID": invalid identifier
```

SQL:

```
    select 
  o.from_crrncy as from_crrncy
, o.to_crrncy as to_crrncy
, o.trade_date as trade_date
, o.settle_date as settle_date
, o.order_id as order_id
, oa.exec_broker as oaexecbroker
, o.target_crrncy as given_ccy
From ts_order o
     inner join ts_order_alloc oa on oa.order_id = o.order_id
     inner join TS_ORDER_SEC_SPEC oss on oss.order_id = o.order_id
```

[image: Database Structure]

Comment: are you able to do `select * from TS_ORDER_SEC_SPEC`

Comment: Could you please paste the entire query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your image it seems that you have lower case columns; try quoting:

```
select 
  o.from_crrncy as from_crrncy
, o.to_crrncy as to_crrncy
, o.trade_date as trade_date
, o.settle_date as settle_date
, o.order_id as order_id
, oa.exec_broker as oaexecbroker
, o.target_crrncy as given_ccy
From ts_order o
     inner join ts_order_alloc oa on oa.order_id = o.order_id
     inner join TS_ORDER_SEC_SPEC oss on oss."order_id" = o.order_id
```

Be careful while creating objects in Oracle; see an example:

```
SQL> create table noCase ( col number);

Table created.

SQL> select col from noCase;

no rows selected

SQL> select COL from noCase;

no rows selected

SQL> create table lowerCase ( "col" number);

Table created.

SQL> select col from lowerCase;
select col from lowerCase
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "COL": invalid identifier


SQL> select COL from lowerCase;
select COL from lowerCase
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "COL": invalid identifier


SQL> select "col" from lowerCase;

no rows selected

SQL> select "COL" from lowerCase;
select "COL" from lowerCase
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "COL": invalid identifier
```

Comment: that quote did it!  Thank you so much!  I'm using database.net, so I wonder if that implicitly adds quotes to column names.  Thanks again!